# GAE serving images through links

Tags: google-app-engine

I wrote a gae python script that would put in different ticker symbols to stockcharts.com and it will grabe the chart image by link using urllib2.

I'm successful in grabbing a list of the chart image links, however, when i try to feed them through a page stockcharts.com won't let me.

Instead of the chart image, it will show "Please visit stockcharts.com to view this chart"
This is an example link:

```
  http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=FUN&p=D&yr=1&mn=0&dy=0&i=p97813671848&r=1395885608674
```

How do i go around that?  I want to be able to view the charts i want in 1 single page by loading all the images.
If i take the links and put them in the browser one by one it would work.

```
for i in range(0,len(charts)):
        self.response.out.write('<img src="' + charts[i] + '"><BR>')
```

thanks!

Comment: stockcharts obviously don't want you to "go around that". So whatever solution you come up with they'll block anyway at some point. Rather you should see if they have an API you can use.

Comment: how do I redirect to the link and for it to process it as if i was pasting that link to the address and pressing enter? When i do an <a src => it would redirect to the link but it will say "Please visit stockcharts.com" but if i press enter on the address bar again, then it will show up.  How do i avoid having to press enter and do a proper redirect?